# Why does fitBounds method work incorrect in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I have following code:

```
function fitBounds() {
        var bounds = calculateBounds();
        if (bounds != undefined) {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
```

In debug I see following information:
[image]

After this row execution I invoke following method in console:

```
map.getBounds
```

and see following result:
[image]

For me it is very strange. Expected result: value equal passed `bounds` argument.

Can I achieve that this method return value like `bounds` ?

### UPDATE

```
function calculateBounds() {
        if (terminalMarkers.length > 0) {
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (i = 0; i < terminalMarkers.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(terminalMarkers[i].getPosition());
            }
        }
        return bounds;
    }
```

**P.S.**

In my bussiness logic I suppose that longitude of second point should be more first.

Comment: what does calculateBounds() do?

Comment: calculate bounds for map) it is doesn't matter

Comment: It kind of does... if you don't aggregate the bounds correctly it will not be a valid LatLngBounds object.

Comment: @Bosken85 topic updated

Comment: The function does seem correct! The only thing i can think of is that your bounds are extended a bit by google's internal logic to show your bounds on the closest compatible zoom level. But this is just speculation! Sorry can't help you any further on this!